# Combine all combinations to get complete sets

Tags: ruby, algorithm

I have an array:

```
arr = [1, 2, 3]
```

I want to find all combinations and then combine the combinations to get arrays that contain all the elements of `arr` only once. The sequence doesn't matter. The first combination should return something like

```
combis = [
  [1], [2], [3],
  [1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 3], 
  [1, 2, 3]
]
```

I need `valid` that has the combinations of `combis` that contain each value from `arr` exactly once. So:

```
valid = [
  [[1], [2], [3]],
  [[1], [2, 3]],
  [[2], [1, 3]],
  [[3], [1, 2]],
  [[1, 2, 3]]
]
```

This gets large very quickly, so I need a way to do this without using the combination function twice and then filtering out the incorrect ones.

I feel I need to use some kind of tree structure and recursion to generate the second set of combinations and stop traversing when it is no longer a valid final set.

Would be great if someone could help me with the (pseudo)code for this.

Comment: It looks like what you want is actually an algorithm to "generate all partitions of a set" (that's what you should Google for). There's got to be some white papers with pseudocode you can implement, which will be way more efficient than the approach you are asking for in your question.

Comment: NP-hard alert! This is equivalent to finding all partitions of a set, a partition being a mutually-disjoint collection of subsets that covers the set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`Enumerator::Lazy`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerator/Lazy.html) to reject unwanted / invalid combinations immediately:

```
combis = 1.upto(arr.size).each_with_object([]) do |i, acc|
  acc.concat arr.combination(i).to_a 
end 
#⇒ [[1], [2], [3], [1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]

valid = 1.upto(arr.size).each_with_object([]) do |i, acc|
  acc.concat(
    #                     ⇓⇓⇓⇓ THIS
    combis.combination(i).lazy.select do |e|
      items = e.flatten
      items.uniq.size == items.size && items | arr == items
    end.to_a
  )
end
#⇒ [[[1, 2, 3]], [[1], [2, 3]], [[2], [1, 3]], [[3], [1, 2]], [[1], [2], [3]]]
```

Comment: Thanks! That actually works, but it still creates all combinations of combis which also gets large very quickly. It is too slow for the size of my arr. Is there any way to speed it up?

Comment: No it does not create all combinations of combined. Read the docs I linked.

Comment: I also have the feeling that `#lazy` doesn't do anything if the intention is to call `#to_a` afterwards. It will still iterate the whole collection since it needs to be converted to an array. Lazy only works when you need a finite amount of elements taken. eg. `(0..Float::INFINITY).lazy.select { |i| (i % 2).zero? }.take(3).to_a` works because of the `.take(3)` when removing *take* you might as well leave out the *lazy* call `(0..Float::INFINITY).select { |i| (i % 2).zero? }.to_a` (try adding *lazy* here and notice the lack of difference)

Comment: I know, but when you call `#to_a` you're essentially saying: *run `#select` for all elements in the collection*. It only works when you're adding a limitation on the amount of elements taken. This can be done by calling `#take` , `#take_while` and maybe some other methods.

Comment: @SanderSchepens Just out of curiosity, what size is your actual array?

Comment: @JohanWentholt you misunderstand how lazy enumerators work in Ruby: `[*1..10].each.lazy.select(&:odd?).each(&method(:puts)).to_a`. It does not produce intermediate arrays, it runs the whole chain for _each_ element in input instead.

Comment: I want to run it for 20 elements in arr. Doing a benchmark now. 4 elements in 0,05 seconds, 5 elements in 1,3 seconds and 6 in 616 seconds. 7 still running after 2 hours.. :) I've tried to read up on the lazy enumerator, but seems I don't get it. It still has to generate the combination that it has to test to be valid, right? And there's a lot of those combinations.. Maybe I'm missing something

Comment: Generate — yes, but one by one, without memory consumption. For 20 elements in any case you need somewhat else approach.

Comment: Aah okay I get it. Memory wasn't a problem until now though. It's just the amount of time. Thanks anyway for the solution. I might have some way to get the number of combis down to around 700. Still large, but maybe manageable. I only need to run it once.